# Sublime Text 2, Sublimelint, summary of problems

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimelinter

I'm starting to use `Sublime Text 2` in favor of Eclipse for developing Python code.

In all I'm liking the change, but one of the things I miss from Eclipse is a convenient "problems" window that shows a summary of all errors and warnings from files in the project. While `sublimelinter` helps, it only works for files that you have open and are editing. It will place a box clearly around the error as you type it, but what if there are other problems in other files that you haven't seen yet? (ie, might have been committed by a coworker, etc)

Does there exist something in Sublime Text 2 that will show a summary of linting output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pylint is first and foremost a command line tool for code analysis.
You can simply run it on a module from the command line and it will generate a whole report with every error/warning within the project.

I don't know if such feature exists from within sublime text but this is not something you will use often. I simply use the command line about once a week to check if I didn't miss anything.

I also use a SublimeTODO plugin, which basically analyses the code looking for TODO comments. Unlike sublimelint, it does generate a report for all the open files or files within a project.